# vb copy line with pull down selection

Tags: vba, excel

I am using Excel 2007. I have 9 columns:

1. Column A is counter (+1)
2. Column B through E are manual data inputs
3. Column F is parent validation
4. Column G is Child validation of F
5. Column H is Vlookup of column G when column F selects Layout and
6. Column J is a Vlookup of column G when column F selects Routing.

I created a macro assigned to a button that copies the line you are on (last line) and inserts it down 1 row and clears the contents of column B through E.

I am looking for a way to reset the column F parent during the copy to Not_Started of the 3 choices: (Not_Started, Layout, Routing).

Below is current macro.

```
Sub Copy_1_Line()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Rows(ActiveCell.Row + 1).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Activate
    ActiveCell.ClearContents
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Activate
    ActiveCell.ClearContents
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Activate
    ActiveCell.ClearContents
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Activate
    ActiveCell.ClearContents
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=1).Activate
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: `I am looking for a way to reset the column F parent during the copy to Not_Started of the 3 choices: (Not_Started, Layout, Routing).` I am not too sure if I understand you correctly. May I see a sample file with just few rows populated?

Answer (score 1):

The selects will slow down your code, removing them will speed up your code and make it easier to maintain.

If I understand correctly, you want the active cell line, column F to show Not Started. If you want the new line to have that, change line

```
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "F") = "Not_Started"
```

to

```
Cells(ActiveCell.Row+1, "F") = "Not_Started"
```

Here is my suggestion:

```
Sub Copy_1_Line()
Application.EnableEvents = False

Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Copy Rows(ActiveCell.Row + 1)
Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 2).Resize(1, 4).ClearContents
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "F") = "Not_Started"

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer that really helped, and its the new line I want to say not_started. But I need to insert the new line as I have calculating rows 4 rows below the last line that only update when you insert.

Comment: I'd suggest defining your calculating formulas with a defined range so you don't have the risk of them not picking up the above. Example: select cell A2, goto to the name manager (Ctrl+F3), define a name as rgCellAbove, with the formula =A1 (no dollars). You can now use that name in your formulas and it will always pick the cell above, as in: =sum(B2:rgCellAbove)

Comment: No my example has 35 line items (item 1 being on line 4, item 35 being on 38), and on line 42 thru 46 have calculations. If the person wants to add/insert 5 new entries, I need for the formulas to update to end on 43 after the final entry is made. ex in column F - =countif(F$4:F$38,"Layout") when updated becomes =countif(F$4:F$43,"Layout"). Also we may want to add/insert at row 10.

Comment: Hi, is the problem solved? You can just keep your code till
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
and then add 
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 2).Resize(1, 4).ClearContents
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, "F") = "Not_Started"

Comment: Yes, but i noticed a problem in column A. When the insert is done the +1 formula is off, I have 2 rows with the same value. I need to select/copy ".row -2, 1"    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 1).Select but how do i paste over 2 rows 1 column: i tried the following:    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 1).Resize(2, 1).Paste , but i get a error.